# Android-How to start and keep service running after first app launch?

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite

I am creating a database on first launch and on a button click I will insert values in the table.Now on that button click itself I will start a service by startService() method,that service will continuously be checking particular column values of table eternally till I explicitly stop service.My question is how to start and keep this service running after first insertion click that I do?Thanks.

```
    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
              //MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
              event=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
              message=ed1.getText().toString();
              MainActivity.myDataBase.openDatabase("/data/data/package/databases/table", null,MainActivity.myDataBase.OPEN_READWRITE);
              MainActivity.myDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                MainActivity.tablename +
                        " Values ('"+ val1 +"','"+ val2 +"','"+ val3 +"','"+ val4 +"','"+ val5 +"');");

        }

    });
}
```

After that 'insert' I would like to start service to 'select' a particular column from the table that I just inserted records into and let that service run forever.Also it should not restart again when press I that same button to save another recors.

PS:I could make another button to start the service but I want to do all activities in one click and not tarnish the user experience.

Comment: Explain more deeply and show what you have tried.

Comment: .My question is how to start and keep this service running after first insertion click  ? and button click itself I will start a service by startService()

Comment: @AnkitMakwana yes I know that.but I had a doubt whether the service will restart while inserting record the second and following times by clicking that button?

Comment: means your confusion in start service with same button again and again right ?

Comment: yup.exactly.is there any solution that you can think of.tried introducing flags but guess flags wont work because their relevance is constrained till each app runtime.

Comment: The code in `onStartCommand` will be run every time you call `startService`. However, the code in `onCreate` will only be run the *first* time you call `startService`.

Comment: ok that rang some bells.will try it out and update you about the same here.thanks a lot u guys.more power to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the `Service` class and call this with `startService`. If you have already successfully done this, there is no additional step. However, Android may temporarily shut it down at times to preserve resources, so if you'd like to decrease the likelihood of this happening, call the `startForeground` method of the service after you start it.